# Doesn't the 22nd amendment prevent Donald Trump from running for president again in 2024?

Tags: united-states, president, presidential-term

In multiple news articles such as ones [here](https://www.cnn.com/2020/11/12/politics/donald-trump-2024-republican-nomination/index.html) and [here](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/trump-run-2024-advisers-say-openly-discussed/), they mention Donald Trump running for president in 2024 because it is projected Joe Biden will be president starting 2021.

I thought the 22nd amendment which said no person can run for president twice nonconsecutively (emphasis mine):

> No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice, and **no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once**

So I have two questions regarding this:

1. Can Donald Trump run as president in 2024 and become president?
2. If not (which seems the case because of the 22nd amendment), why do these news sources not mention that Donald Trump cannot legally do that without an amendment between now and 2024?

Edit: so I understand Grover Cleveland served 2 non-consecutive terms as the 22nd and 24th president of the United States, but my question pertains to modern day politics since the 22nd amendment didn't get ratified until 1951.

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate, though the emphasis isn't really on the bolded part in the amendment: [*In the US, can a former president run again?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/42193)

Comment: Can you explain how you think the 22nd Amendment prohibits Trump from running in 2024?

Comment: There would seem to be another potential problem: even if Trump pardons himself before leaving office, that only applies to Federal crimes.  There are a number of state criminal investigations at the moment (e.g. https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-election-trump-probes-explainer/explainer-citizen-trump-will-face-legal-woes-idUSKBN27P189 ), and there might well be more once he is not shielded by his office.  So if these result in convictions, can Trump run for office while occupying a cell in a state prison?

Comment: @FettFrank where do you get that it would prohibit non-consecutive terms in particular? If it would apply to Trump (which it doesn't), why would it only apply in 2024 but didn't apply already in 2020?

Comment: The quoted text places certain limits on *how many* times a person can be elected President. But it says nothing about whether or not those terms are consecutive.

Comment: Did you completely read the section you quoted? The answer is right there.

Comment: The bolded text says "shall be elected... more than once". Why do you expect this to prevent someone from running additional times, as long as they are only elected at most twice?

Comment: @jamesqf Debs did (though from pen) and still pulled 3.4%.

Comment: @gormadoc: What or who is "Debs"? [Eugene V. Debs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debs_v._United_States) (1919)?

Comment: Ever heard of Grover Cleveland, the 22nd and 24th president?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes.

Comment: @jamesqf: Being convicted of any crime, state or federal, presents no constitutional barrier to being elected President, even if he is still in prison when he's elected. He might not be able to vote for himself however. Also, one might argue that upon election the vice president-elect would immediately become president because "...or Inability to discharge the Powers and Duties of the said Office, the Same shall devolve on the Vice President,.." from Article II.

Comment: **Shouldn't this question's title be reworded?** Questions in the negative imply that the negative proposition is assumed true. The positive phrasing is much more neutral in tone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In the US, can a former president run again?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42193/in-the-us-can-a-former-president-run-again)

Comment: Even though this is clearly about administration and nothing to do with politics as such, "No person shall be elected… President more than twice…" speaks for itself. Equally, the rest is as open to question as many barn doors.

No person who has acted (etc)… seems clearly to mean no Vice President… No (such person) shall be elected to the office of President more than once seems odd.

My interpretation is, that clause aims to treat a promoted VP as though elected, counting a subsequent first actual election as a second.

Either way, nothing there seems to bar Trump from trying again.

Comment: @Punintended, Cleveland was president before the 22 amendment was passed, so he isn't relevant to this question. (The premise of the question is wrong, but Cleveland isn't evidence of it.)

Comment: @prl Oops, good point.  Forgot that wasn't instituted until FDR

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The bolded part doesn't apply to President Trump. Specifically, it includes the following:

> of a term to which some other person was elected President

President Trump is only serving in the term to which he was elected. If, in addition to the current term where he has been elected president, he had also served over two years of a term to which someone else was elected, then the term limit would apply.

So yes, President Trump can run again in 2024 (or any future election until the term limit does kick in) because the term limit doesn't apply (assuming a different president assumes office in 2021).

Comment: Put another way, the 2+ years clause is merely closing a VP loophole. If a vice-president serves 3 years after the president dies, that counts as one of the 2 terms. They can't have 3+4+4 = 11 years as president.

Comment: @OwenReynolds but the real question is, could they have 3+3+4=10 years? Or even 3.5+3.5+4=11 years? Sure, those would be odd circumstances (taking over as VP twice within a year of the election) but I don't think it's forbidden explicitly.

Comment: "assuming he leaves office within two years after President-elect Biden's term begins": Trump ceases to be president at noon on January 20th.  He does not need to take any action to "leave office."

Comment: @JJJ it doesn't need to be "within a year of the election."  Suppose Kamala Harris becomes president before January 20, 2023.  She can only be elected as president once after that, whether in 2024 or 2040.  Alternatively, if she were to become president after that date, she would be eligible to be elected twice, regardless of when.

Comment: @phoog yes, changed it a bit w.r.t. the first comment. As for the VP comment, I was referring to a year within (after) the prior election, otherwise the numbers don't add up to 3.5 on the remainder of the term (it's actually a bit less than a year), but it's not a very relevant number.

Comment: @JJJ oh I see. I misunderstood which election you were speaking of (and actually the relevant date is the inauguration, not the election). But of course it has to be within two years to trigger the amendment.

Comment: @OwenReynolds What if they first serve two terms as President, and *then* get elected Vice-President (or even appointed Vice-President when *another* Vice-President becomes President?)

Comment: @gerrit The 12th Amendment bans people ineligible to become President from being VP.

Comment: The original Article-II rules say electors only vote for president, and 2nd place is VP. So you always had to be president-eligeble to be a VP. The 12th needed to add "VP must meet P requirements" since it split out the vote for VP.

Comment: @JJJ it can be 3+3+3+3+3+3+3+4 = 25 years if the circumstances allow. There's no limit to the number of elections won, years served, or incapacitated Presidents succeeded by a Vice President.

Comment: @Will but after the first one or two, who'd want that VP for a running mate?  They would appear very bad for their Presidents' health

Comment: @ChrisH I mean, I do hope it's far-fetched in all eventualities but probably the most plausible scenario where this constitutional territory would be trodden is not one where Presidents keep unexpectedly falling ill but one where somehow there is such overwhelming public support for one leader and demand for them to serve beyond normal term limits (but not the congressional will to amend the Constitution) that Presidential tickets where the installation of the VP is the express intention keep winning. The Presidents wouldn't have to get ill, just resign or invoke the 25th on themselves.

Comment: @Will that's a disturbing thought but luckily, as you say, far-fetched

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- But the 22nd amendment is silent on whether or not a two-term President can _become_ President again. It only says that they can’t be _elected_ to the office, not that they can’t succeed to it. It would need a Supreme Court ruling.

Comment: @MikeScott but someone who has reached the term limits of the 22nd amendment is not "eligible to the office of President under the Constitution" and so may not become vice president nor assume the office under [3 USC 19](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/19).

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- no, you were right.  Someone who has reached the term limits on the presidency is ineligible to both offices.  The term "ineligible to" includes people who are precluded from being elected to the office, for whatever reason.  When the phrase was first used, the word "electable" did not exist, and the word that described an inability to be elected was "ineligible."

Comment: @phoog: the 22nd doesn’t make one ineligible to the office, it makes one ineligible to be elected.  If taken to literally mean ineligible for the office, that would mean that after the second election, the President would be ineligible to hold the office.  Sworn in, instantly ineligible then removed from office.   That’s what would happen if it came to light that the President was 25 after being sworn in, because a 25 year old is ineligible to **hold** the office.

Comment: @phoog In fact, ["eligible"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eligible) comes from the same Latin [word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eligo) as "elect" -- just different verb endings. "Eligible" has come to broadly mean "meeting minimum qualifications", but originally it essentially meant "electable". The grammar is similar to "dirigible" = "directable".

Comment: @phoog You're right. 22A says elected, and 12A says eligible. I got confused. I think it's *technically* a loophole, but the intent is clear and I have a hard time seeing SCOTUS rule a two-term prez can succeed to the presidency.

Comment: In modern usage at least, "eligible" is a legal term describing whether someone is allowed to become president or not.  "Electable" is more a matter of opinion - i.e. if the person is popular enough to win the votes required to win the election.

Comment: @jmoreno 3 USC 19 is the law that provides for presidential succession beyond the Vice President. Section (e) says that "[Succession rules] shall apply only to such officers as are eligible to the office of President under the Constitution." Thus anyone who cannot be elected President cannot succeed the President either.

Comment: @AndrewRay: Eligible to hold the office and eligible to be elected are not the same thing. A 2 term president is ineligible to be elected to the office the second the term starts, but will hold the office for 4 more years.

Comment: @jmoreno And a president who resigned immediately after the start of their second term and subsequently got appointed a secretary would be passed over in the succession for not being "eligible to the office of President." It does not say "eligible to hold the office of President," but "eligible to the office of President."

Answer (score 32):

The bolded section does not preclude somebody from serving two non-consecutive terms, it says that if somebody serves or acts as president for more than half of a term without being elected president (probably because they were vice president and filled a vacancy), they can only be elected to one full term.

Trump lost the election and will not serve or act as president during the term beginning January 2021, so the bolded section will not apply to him.

Answer (score 19):

This clause would be for a Vice President who becomes president. If Pence had become President for two years and a day because something happened to Trump, then Pence could only be elected once as President. If Trump threw the towel in right now and Pence became President for two months, he could then become President for two terms.

Comment: Not just for Vice President, it's for anyone on the presidential line of succession.

Comment: @ManhattanDevelopment The point of this answer, I assume, is to give any concrete example, since the OP's bold text doesn't explain how one could serve "part of a term to which someone else was elected". Adding in the succession rules might muddle that.

Comment: On the contrary, stating a mistruth (or a partial truth) muddles that.

Comment: Easy folks.  Please don't jump to the lies accusation so quickly.  The point was that the details might distract from the main headline, not that the detail were wrong and omitting them is due to an untruth.  I am disappointed that our current US leadership has lead to discourse that is so black and white and folks being not so nice to each other.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the election stands as it is currently projected he can run again in 2024 as the only limitation on serving is two terms that are 2 years or more in length or being elected twice.

https://www.constituteproject.org/constitution/United_States_of_America_1992

> No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice, and no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once. But this Article shall not apply to any person holding the office of President, when this Article was proposed by the Congress, and shall not prevent any person who may be holding the office of President, or acting as President, during the term within which this Article becomes operative from holding the office of President or acting as President during the remainder of such term.

[Grover Cleveland](https://www.nps.gov/nr/travel/presidents/grover_cleveland_birthplace.html#:%7E:text=Grover%20Cleveland%20Birthplace%2D%2DPresidents%3A%20A%20Discover%20Our%20Shared%20Heritage%20Travel%20Itinerary&text=Born%20in%20this%20modest%20house,serve%20two%20non%2Dconsecutive%20terms.) served two non consecutive terms

> Born in this modest house in Caldwell, New Jersey on March 18, 1837, Stephen Grover Cleveland was the 22nd and 24th president of the United States, the only president to serve two non-consecutive terms.

Comment: I think the Cleveland presidency predates 22nd amendment.

Comment: @JJJ It does but I included it as well as the 22nd amendment to show that it has happened before. The main part of the answer is the 22nd amendment showing that it only cares about being elected twice or serving two terms of more than two years.

Comment: I don't think it reads that way. Even if they have served two times over two years as part of someone else's term, then they are allowed to be elected once.

Comment: @JJJ I don't think it is written to allow for someone to serve more than two terms in office if the person is assuming office from another person. As an example a person moving up from vice president to president three times.

Comment: Yea, there's a bit of discussion about that in [Brythan's answer on the other question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/42195). It seems the amendment doesn't specify that because it only restricts who may be elected.

Comment: @JJJ I think the idea of the 22nd amendment is to limit someone to 8 years (if elected twice) or 10 years is they assume the office from someone else with 2 or fewer years left. And if a former two  term president was to get in the presidential succession chain they would be skipped over as ineligible.

Comment: @JJJ is right.  Whatever the intention of the amendment may have been, what it actually says is that someone who's served more than two years of a term the which someone else is elected may only be elected once.  It does not say that the ability to be elected is further restricted after succeeding to the presidency multiple times.  There is absolutely nothing in the amendment about "serving two terms of more than two years."

Comment: @Joe the 22nd does not in itself prevent a 2 term president from acting as or ascending from vice president to president. The 12th might, if read to assume that the 22nd applies to succession and not just election. Also, it says more than 2 years. So 2 years exactly would not count to disqualify them.

Comment: @cde The 12th amendment which says the VP must be eligible to be president does combine with the 22nd to say that. " But no person constitutionally ineligible to the office of President shall be eligible to that of Vice-President of the United States."

Comment: @joe constitutional scholars argue that qualification for presidents isn't the same as eligibility to be elected, and the ambiguity of the 22nd in not simply saying "ineligible to hold office" instead of elected changes that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, he can.

You say '... which said no person can *run* for president twice...' - it nowhere talks about *running* for president.

You can run for President as often as you want, consecutively or not, twentyfive times if you care (if you live long enough).
Any limitations are about *being elected* for President, and Trump was only elected once so far.

Comment: To emphasise that: somebody could run for president despite the 22nd amendment, he could receive an overwhelming fraction of the "popular vote", he could be nominated as president by a majority in the electoral college, but despite that he could not legitimately /be/ the president. Although it would be a brave man who pointed that out...

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd, "nominated" by the electoral college? I believe the electoral college is who actually elects the President.

Comment: @CramerTV Exactly: they nominate him as president. Or would you prefer "designate"?

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd, Candidates for president are *nominated* by their party. We, the People, vote for *electors* for the party of our preferred candidate. Presidents are then **elected** by the *electors* of the electoral college. And whoever is **elected** by the electoral college **is** the legitimate President.

Comment: Would you settle for anoint? :-)

Comment: Electors are appointed. Article 2. Electors then vote for president.

Answer (score 3):

You are misreading the Amendment.  Basically it is saying that you can’t be elected President to a 3rd term, with a term being defined as having been elected President or having served as President for two years.

So a crazy scenario to show how this works.

President A/VP B are elected, after swearing in ceremony A gets hit in the head by pigeon dropped by a hawk and lapses into a coma for 3 and half years.  Comes out of coma, runs for President with B as VP, wins, gets sworn in again, gets hit in the head by hawk that is diving for a pigeon, lapses into yet another coma and comes out of it after another 3 and half years.  Is told that he can never run for President again. B runs for President for the very first time (after serving 8 years) with A as VP,  wins.  President B gets hit in the head by flying eagle, lapses into coma. A is appointed President and serves for 4 years.  Neither A nor B are eligible to be elected as President.  C decides to run for President with B as running mate on the condition that the swearing in ceremony take place indoors, wins, gets sworn in, slips on banana peel and lapses into coma.  B is appointed President for another 4 years. D runs for President with C as VP, gets sworn in, trips and lapses into a coma. C serves for next 4 years.  C is no longer eligible to run for President.

So, it doesn’t prevent non-consecutive terms, it doesn’t prevent someone from being President for more than 9 years. It disqualifies someone from being eligible to be a candidate after twice having been SELECTED or having previously been selected AND having served for more than 2 years when someone else was selected.

There is no limit on how many times you can run and loose.

Comment: This answer is for the birds. But a bird in the hand is worth two in the [George Bush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Bush).

Comment: Your example is odd and not helpful. Either A could win the presidency a third time, because B was acting president during his comas. Or they could not be elected and hence would also be skipped when freshly inaugurated president B gets eagled (not being eligible for election also prevents succession). Similarly, B would likely be ineligible for the third election period and could not succeed C's banana incident. The maximum term length would be 10 years minus 1 day - nearly 2 years as acting president and then 2 full terms. (or full term 1, 2years acting, full term 2).

Comment: @Chieron the maximum time in office under your theory is actually ten years exactly because someone who assumes the presidency for exactly two years has not "held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected."  There's no need to subtract a day.  (But in fact someone can assume the office multiple times, because subsequent times do not further restrict the ability to be elected, so the maximum time in office is actually unlimited.)

Comment: @Chieron: the Amendment is very specific, it doesn’t say 10 years, in both branches of the condition it says “shall be elected to the office of the President”.  That means ELECTED TO THE OFFICE OF THE PRESIDENT, no more , no less.  A can only be elected to the office twice.  Hard stop.  How much of the term is served is irrelevant.

Comment: Your examples seems wrong. The 3rd election, neither A or B can win. A has been elected 2 times, regardless of being in a coma 75% of the time and not holding the office, and B has held the office/acted as president for more than 2 years each of the first 2 terms. Term 3 cannot happen B as President. AND the 12th amendment likely disqualifies A from running for Vice President. Same for Term 4 with B as Vice President.

Comment: @Chieron The Vice President doesn't get elected to President when the president is removed. So its a bit of a lacking of the 12th, 22nd, and 25th amendments in that case. So the 25th alone, if the 12th isn't interpreted to incorporate it, may not prevent the Vice President from ascending. Nor would it apply to others who act as president. ALSO, that would imply that there is no max time someone can serve as succession to president, as long as they don't do it for more than 2 years (even non-continuous) in a single term. So 4 years + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 ad nausea.

Comment: @cde possibly, however, I suspect that the wording "for more than two years of a term" could also be interpreted as being the total time of acting president. 
And yes, the 22nd amendment is not enough, but it doesn't exist in a vaccuum and that's why the examples are problematic. 
@ phoog You are right about the one day. And yeah, the wording is awkward. They should've written it as an explicit term limit. There is indeed nothing prevent infinite successions. Reminds me of Putin's switch with Medvedev to circumvent Russia's term limit..

Comment: @cde: B can be elected President at that point, because while B has **been** President for 2 terms,  B was never **elected** President, thus neither condition of the 22nd prevent it.  And the 12th doesn’t prevent it because, both A and B are still eligible to hold the office. Only 2 things would definitely make them **ineligible** to be President, impeachment or treason (insanity or dementia might).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very confusing.  You seem to be held up on the two terms being non-consecutive, but there is no wording in the 22nd amendment that would seem to have anything to do with that.

> 1. Can Donald Trump run as president in 2024 and become president?

He can run, and if he wins he can become president.  He has only been elected to the office once, in 2016.  Nothing in the amendment prevents him from being elected a second time, no matter how much time has passed.

I think you're stuck up on the section you mark in bold:

> **no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once**

Donald Trump has never held the office of President or acted as President at all when some other person was elected President, let alone for two years.  He's only served as president for the term where he was elected himself.

Answer (score -1):

The amendment has 4 clauses. The 3rd is a grandfather clause no longer important and 4th is regarding when it goes into effect.

Of the 2 you care about, clause 1 is:

> No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice

As it applies to Trump, clause 1 only applies if Trump is elected twice. He has not been, having only been elected somehow in 2016.

Clause 2 also does not apply either.

> no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once

Clause 2 applies to anyone, who either become president (only the Vice President becomes president when the president is removed) or acts as president (everyone else in the line of succession), for at least 2 years in that 4 year term. It may not require it to be a consecutive 2 years. Trump was impeached, but not removed, has not been incapacitated, or killed, so no one has replaced him this term, and he has never been in the line of succession for previous presidents.

---

Since it has never been tested, there is a possibility for the 25th Amendment ***not to apply*** to the 12th Amendment. Without the 12th amendment, incorporating the 25th, then someone who was elected to the office of president, or even ascending or acted as president, could run for Vice President, and then would be in the line of succession. Obama could, in theory, run for Vice President, and then, in theory, become President through succession for that term. And nothing would stop him from doing it multiple times. Short of an amendment or SCOTUS ruling, and the practicality of his ticket winning multiple times.