# US presidential election: winning three times

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump, constitution

Donald Trump has, according to his claims, been elected president twice by popular vote. However he has been denied the office due to claimed malfeasance of the state governments.

If his claims are correct, does the US Constitution allow him to stand a third time?

Comment: He has been denied the office because he failed to win a majority of Electoral College delegates.

Comment: Also, it sounds as if you may be under the impression that a candidate can only run for office twice. That is not correct—they can only serve as president twice (with some caveats). For better or for worse (probably the latter), nothing prevents Donald Trump from running again in 2024.

Comment: https://constitution.congress.gov/constitution/amendment-22/#:~:text=No%20person%20shall%20be%20elected,the%20President%20more%20than%20once. *No person shall be **elected** to the office of the President more than twice, and no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once.*

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica According to the question, Trump claims he was elected in 2020. That would make him inelligible

Comment: @Obie: I am emphatically not under that impression. However his claim is that he /was/ elected by the popular vote, and Amendment 22 does not allow for a disparity between the popular vote and the action of the Electors.

Comment: @xyldke which was a point I tried to make clearly. I am uncomfortable with the edit to my question's title.

Comment: "Amendment 22 does not allow for a disparity between the popular vote and the action of the Electors": why do you this is true? The popular vote has nothing to do with the 22nd amendment.  Only the outcome of the electoral college vote determines who is elected president.

Comment: "If his claims are correct". But they are not. It does not matter what Trump claims. What matters is what actually happened. He only won once. In most cases, you would expect that a claim of "I won the elections of the POTUS" would be backed by facts, but very little of what Trump says is backed by facts.

Comment: You didn't have to accept *my* edit to make it less controversial, but *winning three times* as a title stinks of election denial.  -1

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I agree, the whole thing stinks. But the point is that Trump- and his supporters- claim that he won twice, and if that claim actually had any validity then he should not be offering himself for election a third time. The fact that he is prepared to can only be interpreted as illustrating his contempt for the constitution, for the office to which he aspires, and for the American people as a whole.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Apologies, it seems I misjudged your PoV.  The body of the Q is somewhat more circumspect in that regards.  But my point stands "winning 3 times" *looks* like the person asking the question thinks Trump won in 2020.  You have -5 overall, but it's likely not because people are upset about a technical Q about the 22nd amendment.  I wager they perceive election denial, from the title.  It's your Q, you are certainly the boss with it.  But your comments and actual position here - that the election was run fairly - don't seem to line up with the title.

Comment: Now, wrt to his contempt, not really.  If he feels he won the vote, the fact remains that his election did not take effect.  I.e. the legal system can't both claim he did not get elected the *second* time *and* bar him from running on the basis that it would be a *third* time.  IF the election had been fraudulent - it wasn't - he'd be fully in his legal rights to run again as his being elected had not been recognized.  There are no limits on how many times someone can run and not win.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Could *"winning" three times* be a compromise? That way you keep the original claim while disavowing it.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I'm only a very occasional SE user, and am OK with losing a few points. It's actually quite interesting, since the question appears to get the occasional -1 (presumably from somebody judging it by its title) and the occasional +1 (presumably after somebody else has read it and deciphered my phrasing). My apologies (to everybody) if it was "excessively hedged" but I really do feel that Trump's in a "Catch 22" situation: if he lost then he's got no excuse for holding a grudge, but if (as he claims) he won then he shouldn't be standing.

Comment: @xyldke I've considered that, but particularly since there's an unambiguous answer I'm inclined to let the question wither rather than trying to keep it alive with a newly-timestamped edit. If only Trump would follow my example...

Comment: "The fact that he is prepared to can only be interpreted as illustrating his contempt for the constitution": no, there's another interpretation, which is that he is well aware that his claim to have won the 2020 election is completely false.  This is in line with other false claims he has knowingly made, such as the number of levels in various buildings that he has built or owned; for example, see https://www.businessinsider.com/trump-tower-is-not-as-tall-as-trump-says-2016-10 (It is a common practice in the industry.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no contradiction between the 22nd Amendment and President Trump's position that he won the 2020 Presidential Election vote with the electorate. The 22nd Amendment states:

> No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice

Furthermore, Article II Clause 3 stipulates how the votes for President should be counted and the President elected - and it doesn't mention the popular vote at all. Rather, it refers solely to the votes in the electoral college. President Trump does not deny that the electoral college voted to install President Biden - that was the whole point of his actions with regard to pressuring Vice President Pence not to certify the slate of electors on January 6th.

Trump's position is that despite him winning the 2020 election with the American public, due to voter fraud and vote rigging he was denied election to the presidency with the electorate that matters - the electoral college. Therefore, he was not elected to the office of the President more than once, and can run again in 2024 and be elected without being in conflict with the 22nd amendment.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Article II Clause 3 trumps the 22nd Amendment.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd not that it trumps it, but that it defines what it means to be elected to the presidency. Amendment 22 then uses that definition.

Comment: It is worth adding that Trump's position does not have any legal foundation. He was not prevented from winning by voter fraud or any of the other various conspiracies he likes to bring up.

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/60208/doesnt-the-22nd-amendment-prevent-donald-trump-from-running-for-president-again?rq=1

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd There is no contradiction between Article II Clause 3 and the 22nd amendment. There is a contradiction between Article II Clause 3 and the 12th amendment, and the 12th amendment wins. Amendments add things that weren't in the original constitution or override things that were in the original constitution or in a previous amendment. There is no contradiction in the former case. In the latter case here there is a contradiction, with the newest amendment trumping the older stuff. (Continued)

Comment: What the 22nd Amendment does contradict is Article II Clause 5. There was nothing in the Constitution that prevented FDR from serving for four terms. Now there is, thanks to the 22nd Amendment. BTW, Trump only served one term. His claims are irrelevant. He is eligible to run in 2024.